# Xcode won't compile due to LLVM error

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm trying to write a C++ program in Xcode.
My code seems not to have any issues, but when I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::hash<std::1::pair<unsigned long, unsigned long> >'
```

This error would apparently be at line 1008 of LLVM's `type_traits` file.
I thought it was some library error, but when I tried to compile a simple Hello World, it worked fine.

Anybody know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `std::hash` specialisation for `std::pair` (or `std::tuple`). It's one of the most ridiculous features of the c++ standard and it cripples the library.

This is probably occurring because you're using a `std::pair` as a key in an `unordered_map`.

What you need to do is include boost: `<boost/functional/hash.hpp>` and declare `boost::hash<std::pair<X, Y>>` as the 3rd template parameter of your map.

Until `std::hash` is fixed, it's almost useless.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, except I'm using an `unordered_set`. Now I just need to understand how to include Boost libraries in Xcode and I should be good to go.

Comment: boost.functional is entirely header-only so you just need the set the include path to point to the boost source.